# asynchronous loading of grid view items

Tags: android, gridview, asynchronous

i need to load the items of the grid view asynchronously. Is it possible and how

Comment: Where are the items loaded from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look at `AsyncTask` in the SDK documentation for starters.  It will give you an easy way of processing in the background while giving you an easy way of interacting with the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brief example of using AsyncTask here on the [Google Android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)